# Collecting S/Ns and Model Name

Tags: macos

I just started at a scale-up as their first IT Engineer, and boy, what a mess it is. Company exists for 10 years, but they just started to have an IT department now for 4-5 months. All devices (Macs) that have been given out in the last 10 years, are all unmanaged, and set-up as personal. No MDM, no rules, nothing.

Now it's my task to audit and index everything we have.

I wonder if there is an easier way to retrieve someone's serial number, and the model name (example: MacBook Pro, 16-inch, 2021, and if possible, more info like RAM and storage, but this is more than enough) of the device that they are using, other than to manually open the about and more info...

I was thinking of using Automator or something, but I couldn't find any info on that online, unfortunately.

Hopefully someone can help, or guide me toward the best direction, because I don't want to manually reach out to all the people...

Cheers!

Comment: Do you have network/remote access to the Macs? Do you have access to an administrator account?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to automate this. One way is to use the **`system_profiler`** command to retrieve the specific data that you're interested in. This is the command-line equivalent of the System Information tool that runs when you do *About This Mac -> More Info*.

Since there's lot of available system information available about each Mac, the data is grouped into categories. To list these categories, run

```
system_profiler -listDataTypes | sort
```

Then you can specify the names of one or more categories to the `system_profiler` command to retrieve the information associated with that category.

For example, the system's **model name** and **serial number** are found in the `SPHardwareDataType` category, and the system's **DRAM configuration** is in the `SPMemoryDataType` category. So if I wanted to quickly collect data from both categories, I could run

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType SPMemoryDataType
```

Example output:

```
Hardware:

    Hardware Overview:

      Model Name: Mac Classic
      Model Identifier: MacClassic1,1
      Processor Name: Motorola MC68000
      Processor Speed: 8.0 MHz
      Number of Processors: 1
      Total Number of Cores: 1
      L2 Cache (per Core): 0 KB
      L3 Cache: 0 MB
      Hyper-Threading Technology: Disabled
      Memory: 4 MB
      Boot ROM Version: 123.14.5.0.0
      Serial Number (system): CA5B061498D94
      Hardware UUID: 19CB09DD-79D3-4B26-922F-B365549A6B22
      Activation Lock Status: Disabled

Memory:

    Memory Slots:

      ECC: Disabled
      Upgradeable Memory: Yes

        BANK 0/ChannelA-SIMM0:

          Size: 2 MB
          Type: SDR
          Speed: 6.67 MHz
          Status: OK
          Manufacturer: Micron
          Part Number: -
          Serial Number: -

        BANK 0/ChannelA-SIMM1:

          Size: 2 MB
          Type: SDR
          Speed: 6.67 MHz
          Status: OK
          Manufacturer: Micron
          Part Number: -
          Serial Number: -
```

Depending on your needs, you can then apply all sorts of text postprocessing to the above output (e.g., `grep`). You can also have `system_profiler` emit JSON- or XML-formatted output instead of plaintext, using the `-json` or `-xml` command-line arguments, respectively. See `man system_profiler` for more info.

Comment: How could this be applied to a huge number of machines, without having to walk to each one of them?

Comment: @nohillside I doubt there's an easy way to run the script on each Mac without physical interaction. Remote propagation and execution of scripts is something computers have been trying to prevent for a while!

Comment: @benwiggy well, with remote access via ssh enabled it would be rather easy. But most probably this isn’t set up either.

Comment: Probably a walking exercise will be good to establish exactly what assets are still accessible within the company, find out if any machines have gone walkies or otherwise compromised. No easy way round it other than a physical inspection IMHO.